# Problem post data with Angular in MongoDB

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i'm trying to do a crud in Angular 14.

All works fine, but when i put in my form an input to update my data, this crashed.
That input are the first of my form.

This is my component.html

```
<form>
     <input type="hidden" name="_id" [(ngModel)]="orderService.selectedOrder._id">
     <input id="client" type="text" class="form-control" name="client" placeholder="Client name" [(ngModel)]="orderService.selectedOrder.client"/>
     <input id="client" type="text" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Price" [(ngModel)]="orderService.selectedOrder.price"/>
</form>
```

This is my component.ts

```
  addOrder(form: NgForm){
    if(form.value._id){
      this.orderService.updateOrder(form.value).subscribe(
        (res) => {
          //console.log(res);
          form.reset();
          this.getOrders();
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
    }else{
    // Here i want to skip form.value._id in createOrder()
      this.orderService.createOrder(form.value).subscribe(
        res => { 
          form.reset();
          this.getOrders();
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      )
    }
  }
```

And finally my orderService

```
  createOrder(order: Order){
    return this.http.post(this.URL_API, order);
  }
  updateOrder(order: Order){
    return this.http.put(`${this.URL_API}/${order._id}`, order);
  }
```

When i remove the hidden input, the problem of create new data are solved, but i cant update data.

I think the problem is when I create a new order, it takes the value of the _id input value from the createOrder method. I don't know how to remove this value when making the post from my method.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What's the `Order`'s type structure?

Comment: Depending on your Order structure, a simple solution might be to make _id attribute optional in that structure